# Call to a member function where() on array laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, controller

I have two tables **tbl_law_master** & **tbl_law_sub_master**
on both these tables there is a column named as **assigned_to**, this column stores user's id.

my task is to get **sublaw** from tbl_law_sub_master for particular **user's id** by joining **law_id** of tbl_law_master.

this is my code,

```
$law_id = $_GET['law_id'];

$sublaw = DB::table('tbl_law_sub_master')
            ->select('tbl_law_sub_master.*', 'tbl_law_master.lm_id', 'tbl_law_master.law_name', 'tbl_law_master.id as lawId')
            ->leftJoin('tbl_law_master', 'tbl_law_master.id', '=', 'tbl_law_sub_master.lm_id')
            ->where('tbl_law_sub_master.lm_id', $law_id)
            ->orderBy('type_of_event', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('section', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('rules', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('notification', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('circular', 'asc')->get();

if (!in_array(Auth::user()->role, [1, 7])) 
{
   $sublaw = $sublaw->where('tbl_law_master.assigned_to', Auth::user()->id);
}
```

it shows me **error** as

> Call to a member function where() on array

Comment: So what's the problem ?

Comment: @MahdiYounesi problem is my code is not returning data for particular user id

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you already called `get()` of your query then called `where()` again.

You should use where clause function like this

```
$sublaw = DB::table('tbl_law_sub_master')
        ->select('tbl_law_sub_master.*', 'tbl_law_master.lm_id', 'tbl_law_master.law_name', 'tbl_law_master.id as lawId')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_law_master', 'tbl_law_master.id', '=', 'tbl_law_sub_master.lm_id')
        ->where(function($query) use ($law_id) {
            $query->where('tbl_law_sub_master.lm_id', $law_id);
            if (!in_array(Auth::user()->role, [1, 7])) 
            {
                $query->where('tbl_law_master.assigned_to', Auth::user()->id);
            }
        })
        ->orderBy('type_of_event', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('section', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('rules', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('notification', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('circular', 'asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call get after the last `where` statement

```
$sublaw = DB::table('tbl_law_sub_master')
        ->select('tbl_law_sub_master.*', 'tbl_law_master.lm_id', 'tbl_law_master.law_name', 'tbl_law_master.id as lawId')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_law_master', 'tbl_law_master.id', '=', 'tbl_law_sub_master.lm_id')
        ->where('tbl_law_sub_master.lm_id', $law_id)
        ->orderBy('type_of_event', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('section', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('rules', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('notification', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('circular', 'asc');

if (!in_array(Auth::user()->role, [1, 7])) 
{
  $sublaw = $sublaw->where('tbl_law_master.assigned_to', Auth::user()->id)->get();
}
```